# i'm using hyperledger fabric v1, but the network wont start. The following error occurs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

```
   =====================================================
   -----> starting network
   =====================================================
```

Starting business network from archive: zerotoblockchain-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: zerotoblockchain-network@0.1.5
    Description: Zero to Blockchain tutorial network

Processing these Network Admins: 
    userName: admin

✔ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Successfully created business network card:
    Filename: networkadmin.card

Command succeeded

```
   =====================================================
   -----> importing networkadmin card
   =====================================================
```

Error: Card already exists: admin@zerotoblockchain-network
Command failed

```
   =====================================================
   -----> pinging admin@zerotoblockchain-network card
   =====================================================
```

Error: Card not found: admin@zerotoblockchain-network
Command failed

```
   =====================================================
   -----> starting REST server
   =====================================================

   network archive, start and deploy script for the Zero To Blockchain Series
   This has been tested on Mac OSX thru High Sierra and Ubuntu V16 LTS
   This script will create your Composer archive
```

> Parameters:
>          Network Name is:  zerotoblockchain-network 
>          =====================================================
>          -----> testing rest server 
>           when this completes, 
>            go to your favorite browser 
>           and enter localhost:3000/explorer 
>          =====================================================
>          =====================================================
>          -----> starting rest server v0.15 for admin@zerotoblockchain-network
>          =====================================================
>   Discovering types from business network definition ...
>   Connection fails: Error: Card not found: admin@zerotoblockchain-network
>   It will be retried for the next request.
>   Exception: Error: Card not found: admin@zerotoblockchain-network
>   { Error: Card not found: admin@zerotoblockchain-network
>       at IdCard.fromDirectory.catch.cause (/home/nikhil/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/cardstore/filesystemcardstore.js:74:27)
>       at 
>     cause: 
>      { Error: Unable to read required file: metadata.json
>       at newErrorWithCause (/home/nikhil/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/idcard.js:36:19)
>       at fs.readFile.catch.cause (/home/nikhil/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-common/lib/idcard.js:326:23)
>       at 
>        cause: 
>         { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/nikhil/.composer/cards/admin@zerotoblockchain-network/metadata.json'
>           errno: -2,
>           code: 'ENOENT',
>           syscall: 'open',
>           path: '/home/nikhil/.composer/cards/admin@zerotoblockchain-network/metadata.json' } } }

Answer (score 0):

While not efficient, [The docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org)(step one) say that you have to remove all cards before deploying a new network. I've had similar issues. I usually just start from scratch if I am having trouble with card imports. Also, you can do `composer card list` in your terminal to view the exact name of the card. You may be assuming that it is `admin@zerotoblockchain-network`.

Comment: please tell me how can solve this problem, please tell me the commands and the steps i need to follow. Thank You

Comment: It is possible the card that exists was created using a composer setup. Kindly go to the link I had posted earlier. Alternatively, do `composer card delete admin@zerotoblockchain-network` then import the one you are trying to import. It already says it exists, perhaps due to similar card names. The content of the cards could be different.